# hibernate configuration: I have already set useSSL=false, but still got the warning

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, ssl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schedule?useSSL=false&amp;autoReconnect=true </property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">1234</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect"
>org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class"
>thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class"
>org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql"
>true</property>

     <property name="format_sql">true</property>

     <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">100</property>
        <mapping resource="model/modelmap.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration >
```

This is my hibernate configuration xml file, I have already set `useSSL=false`, but still got the warning :

> WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity
>   verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+
>   and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default
>   if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing
>   applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set
>   to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting
>   useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server
>   certificate verification.

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: `<propertyname="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schedule?useSSL=false&amp;autoReconnec=true </property>` there are some errors or typos: propertyname, autoReconnec. Try to correct and I read about useSSL as *last* URL parameter. Should made no diference, but who knows ?

Comment: Sorry about those errors, which is caused by the copy of the file. I tried to switch the postion of useSSL and autoRecoonect. It still does not work. <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schedule?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false </property>

Answer (score 3):

Even I faced the same error, the issue was the sql-connector version and and MySql80 instance was not matching, as soon as I updated the connector version to 8.0.21 the problem was resolved...